# What is the PySerial equivalent of MATLAB's serial fwrite()

Tags: matlab, pyserial

I have been going through a documentation code where it uses MATLAB's `serial` function to open COM port and write some data using `fwrite()`. In that code, they have a snippet like following:

```
...
s = 0;
z = double('v');
fwrite(p,z)
while(s~=1 )
  s = fread(p,1);
end
...
```

Seems like they store ascii value of character `v` which is 118 and write that value to the port object `p`. Now, I want to use `PySerial` library for doing the exact same thing. PySerial has a `write` method which can takes something like `ser.write(b'hello')`. How should I use this method to pass the value of `v` like the MATLAB code intended to do? Any explanation is appreciated.